# HTML/js select audio output device in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have a created a simple soundboard in HTML which includes simple lines like this:

```
<body>
    <audio id="sound1" src="mysound.wav"></audio>
    <button class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play()">My sound</button>
</body>
```

Is there any way the user can select which audio output device the sound will be played through, with a dropdown menu or similar?

Comment: The browser is not aware of audio devices. They are controlled at an OS level.

Comment: @Tomm That's not the case any more, WebRTC has access to I/O devices.

Answer (score 2):

Now it is possible.

First you can gather possible audiooutput devices by running `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` and filtering found devices by property 'kind' equal to 'audiooutput'.

Then you should use `setSinkId()` method of DOM's audio/video element. Looks like you have to run setSingId(someSelectedDeviceId) for each video/audio element on your HTML-page

This is quite new feature that still not supported by Safari.
But Chrome and partially FireFox already have this support
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/setSinkId

Answer (score -1):

Here is the example how to change `audio.src` via `select`:

```js
function play() {
  document.getElementById('sound1').play()
  console.log(document.getElementById('sound1').getAttribute('src') + " starts playing")
}

function changeSound() {
  document.getElementById('sound1').src = document.getElementById('select').value
  console.log("selected sound: " + document.getElementById('sound1').src)
}
```

```html
<audio id="sound1" src="mysound1.wav"></audio>
<select id="select" onchange="changeSound()">
  <option value="mysound1.wav">mysound1.wav</option>
  <option value="mysound2.wav">mysound2.wav</option>
  <option value="mysound3.wav">mysound3.wav</option>
</select>
<button class="button" onclick="play()">My sound</button>
```